# Supervised learning, unsupervised learning and reinforcement learning: Workflow basics

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, reinforcement-learning

### Supervised learning

- 1) A human builds a classifier based on *input* and *output* data
- 2) That classifier is trained with a training set of data
- 3) That classifier is tested with a test set of data
- 4) Deployment if the *output* is satisfactory

*To be used when, "I know how to classify this data, I just need you(the classifier) to sort it."*

Point of method: To class labels or to produce real numbers

### Unsupervised learning

- 1) A human builds an algorithm based on *input* data
- 2) That algorithm is tested with a test set of data (in which the algorithm creates the classifier)
- 3) Deployment if the *classifier* is satisfactory

*To be used when, "I have no idea how to classify this data, can you(the algorithm) create a classifier for me?"*

Point of method: To class labels or to predict (PDF)

### Reinforcement learning

- 1) A human builds an algorithm based on *input* data
- 2) That algorithm presents a *state* dependent on the *input* data in which a user rewards or punishes the algorithm via the *action* the algorithm took, this continues over time
- 3) That algorithm learns from the reward/punishment and updates itself, this continues
- 4) It's always in production, it needs to learn real data to be able to present actions from states

*To be used when, "I have no idea how to classify this data, can you classify this data and I'll give you a reward if it's correct or I'll punish you if it's not."*

Is this the kind of flow of these practices, I hear a lot about what they do, but the *practical* and *exemplary* information is *appallingly* little!

Comment: Really liked the way you presented your question. I found this answer helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/522/92255

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am no expert and I even have never done something with reinforcement learning (yet), so any feedback would be welcome...

Here is an answer that adds some tiny mathematical notes to your list and some different thoughts on when to use what. I hope the enumeration is self-explanatory enough:

## Supervised

1. We have data $\mathcal{D} = \{(\boldsymbol{x}_0,y_0), (\boldsymbol{x}_1,y_1), \ldots, (\boldsymbol{x}_n,y_n)\}$
2. We look for a model $g$ that minimises some loss/cost measure $L(y_i, g(\boldsymbol{x}_i))$ for all points $0 \leq i < l$
3. We evaluate the model by computing the loss/cost $L$ for the rest of the data ($l \leq i \leq n$) in order to get an idea how well the model generalises

> We can give examples, but we cannot give an algorithm to get from input to output

Setting for classification and regression

## Unsupervised

1. We have data $\mathcal{D} = \{\boldsymbol{x}_0, \boldsymbol{x}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{x}_n\}$
2. We look for a model $g$ that gives us some insight in our data.
3. We have little to no measures to say whether we did something useful/interesting

> We have some data, but we have no idea where to start looking for useful/interesting stuff

Setting for clustering, dimensionality reduction, finding hidden factors, generative models, etc.

## Reinforcement

1. We have no data
2. We construct a model $g$ that generates data $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ (often called actions), which can be based on measurements and/or previous actions, in an attempt to maximise some reward measure $R(\boldsymbol{x}_i)$, which is generally not known to the model (it needs to be learned as well).
3. We evaluate by means of the reward function after it had some time to learn.

> We have no idea how to do something, but we can say whether it has been done right or wrong

This seems especially useful for sequential decision tasks.

References:
[Si, J., Barto, A., Powell, W. and Wunsch, D. (2004) Reinforcement Learning and Its Relationship to Supervised Learning, in Handbook of Learning and Approximate Dynamic Programming, John Wiley & Sons, Inc., Hoboken, NJ, USA. doi: 10.1002/9780470544785.ch2](http://www-anw.cs.umass.edu/pubs/2004/barto_d_04.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very nice compact introduction to the basic ideas!

### Reinforcement Learning

I think your use case description of reinforcement learning is not exactly right. The term *classify* is not appropriate. An better description would be:

> I don't know how to *act* in this *environment*, can you find a good *behavior* and meanwhile I'll give you *feedback*.

In other words, the goal is rather to **control** something well, than to *classify* something well.

#### Input

- The **environment** which is defined by

  - all possible states
  - possible actions in the states
- The **reward function** dependent on the state and/or action

#### Algorithm

- The agent

  - is in a **state**
  - takes an **action** to transfer to another state
  - gets a **reward** for the action in the state

#### Output

- The agent wants to find an optimal **policy** which maximizes the reward